# OpenLDAP - Named user connection fails

Tags: windows, anonymous, openldap

I am trying to setup a basic ldap server/client scenario. I downloaded openldap for windows and installed it. I am starting the server successfully with the command,

```
slapd -d 1
```

I tried to use various clients (commandline, LDAP Browser, phpLDAPadmin) to connect and do a search, it works with 'anonymous access' but it fails every time I try the same with root user/password and says 'failed to connect to ldap://localhost:389'.  Same thing works if i connect anonymously.

What could be the problem ?

Here's my slapd.conf

```
ucdata-path ./ucdata
include ./schema/core.schema
pidfile ./run/slapd.pid
argsfile ./run/slapd.args
database bdb
suffix "dc=guessant,dc=org"
rootdn "cn=Manager,dc=guessant,dc=org"
rootpw secret
directory ./data
```

I am using Login DN as  "cn=Manager,dc=guessant,dc=org"  and password as "secret"

Comment: You haven't provided much in the way of information. Is that really all the error says? Nothing about the bind failing? What shows up in the slapd window?

Comment: It has been fixed now .. problem was with PHP mcrypt and phpLdapAdmin.  Apparantly there's an issue with PHP 5.2. and figured out that upgrading to 5.3 + or removing mcrypt usage, would fix it. I chose the later, for the timebeing atleast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been fixed now .. problem was with PHP mcrypt and phpLdapAdmin. Apparantly there's an issue with PHP 5.2. and figured out that upgrading to 5.3 + or removing mcrypt usage, would fix it. I chose the later, for the timebeing atleast